# Power Automate Handle ñ foreign character in filename

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I do some parsing for file name based on the `Content-Disposition` header field using the following expression:

```
split(outputs('HTTP')['headers']?['Content-Disposition'],'"')[1]
```

This function splits on `"` and returns the 2nd element

Usually the `Content-Disposition` field is returned like:

> attachment; filename="Filename.pdf"

However I encountered a problem when the filename had a foreign character in it and it came in the format of:

> attachment; filename*=UTF-8''Filename with %C3%B1.pdf

which is the utf-8 reprentation for `Filename with ñ.pdf`

How do I account for this in my logic to return only the filename?

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced in my environment (Logic apps) and I do not see any issue for me and below are my expected results:

**`Design:`**

[image]

```
split(triggerBody()['$multipart'][0]['headers']?['Content-Disposition'],'"')[3]
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

I would suggest you to use Logic apps for this as i received what i expected.

**`Update:`**

For this, you need to use condition like if string contains ", split like above  answer and if it is false split like below:

**`Condition to use:`**

[image]

```
split(outputs('Compose'),' ')[2]
```

[image]

taken hard coded input as i am not facing this issue.

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: The server I am downloading from reports the `Contest-Disposition` as `attachment; filename*=UTF-8''Filename with %C3%B1.pdf`. Splitting by `"` does nothing because there is no double quote in this string

Comment: Updated answer to try to get just name for you.